# tsql: Delete behavior

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to delete an order that has a header, subheader and line item details, before writing out the same order with whatever the replacement subheader, line item details might now be. I'm getting a pk violation error when I try to write back the newer version with the changes. After analysis, I see that even though my DELETE statements appear to work, after issuing them (e.g. x rows affected) --the target table remains unchanged. So, that would explain the pk vio issue. What am I missing?

Here's one of the statements:

```
       -- detail level (drop products)
       DELETE dprods FROM [SQLsever].[WIP].[order].DropProducts as dprods
        INNER JOIN #dropprods t on t.OrderId = dprods.OrderId
          AND t.OrderDropId = dprods.OrderDropId
          AND t.DropProdId = dprods.DropProdId;
```

after issuing the statement, I still have all 200+ rows in the target table AND I have the 200+ ids in the #dropprods temp table. Why?

**  *EDITED TO BETTER DEFINE PROBLEM* *********************
The DELETE statements were NOT the issue. The issue is tied to a set of nested/named transactions. The DELETE statements are under one, the INSERT statements under another. Here's what I have. It's obviously wrong. What I am trying to do is assure that I don't commit a DELETE before I know I'll have a good replacement INSERT.  Here's what I've done:
***** EDITED T-SQL WITH SAVE TRANSACTION FIX *** 
This TSQL will work now.

```
   -- CHANGED
   BEGIN TRANSACTION
   SAVE TRANSACTION process_orders
    BEGIN TRY
    -- detail level 
    DELETE lprods FROM [SQLServer].[WIP].[order].LiftProducts as lprods
     INNER JOIN #liftprods t on t.OrderId = lprods.OrderId
      AND t.OrderLiftId = lprods.OrderLiftId
      AND t.LiftProdId = lprods.LiftProdId;
           -- the rest of the deletes 
            --NOTE: No commit transaction here; saving it to the end
     END TRY
     BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT 
          ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber, 
          ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
          ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
         IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
           ROLLBACK TRANSACTION process_orders;
       END CATCH

       BEGIN TRANSACTION 
        -- CHANGED
        SAVE TRANSACTION process_orders
       BEGIN TRY     
             -- CHANGED
                COMMIT TRANSACTION process_orders;     
       END TRY
       BEGIN CATCH
          SELECT 
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber, 
            ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
              ROLLBACK TRANSACTION process_orders ;
       END CATCH
```

Comment: No idea, are you planning on entering this in the world obfuscation championships? DropOrder, OrderDrop dprods, t... If we worked together, me and you would be falling out big style. Aside from forgetting to commit a transaction, if you are getting reported deleted they aren't the ones you think they are. You might want to look up cascading deletes...

Comment: Thanks for responding Tony. 5 minutes ago I took out all the named transactions and viola! The delete worked. Thank heavens. I didn't think I lost my mind. Well, not in this arena anyway! :) I'm updating the problem descriptin with the transaction issue.

Comment: Good guess on my part, but it was a guess. :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to remove transaction names after ROLLBACK TRANSACTION. Inner transactions are not allowed to be rolled back - only outermost transactions can be rolled back.

Second, SQL server ignores commit of inner transactions (e.g. locks wait till outermost transactions is commited and then release). So you only need one COMMIT TRANSACTION without transaction name.

Your code should have no problems running if you need to be assured that:

- if delete succeedes you start inserts, else you discard changes and
- if those inserts succeed you accept changes, otherwise discard all

If you need to be extra assured before you COMMIT (say: another developer writes insert code in some SP, insert code is really big... etc), you can use your #liftprods temp table (which obviously contains keys to delete/insert) and check if keys match to items you think should be inserted. If not, issue RAISERROR('Some message', 16, 1) which will rollback transaction.

Comment: thanks for responding--yes, it sure does ignore commits of inner transactions. I solved this by naming the first transaction process_orders, then a SAVE TRANSACTION, which I added to on the INSERTS. Works like a magic spell now! :)

Comment: Well, its ok to save a transaction. However, solution I have proposed should be valid as well, because it doesn't commit deletes until it knows inserts are correctly issued, and that was what you wanted, right? ;)